# What is the best way to load heavy bitmap in the imageview?

Tags: android

I as a new programmer, totally confused of the `OutOfMemoryException` whenever I use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,option)` method which `returns` `Bitmap` object. As every application have its `virtual machine` budget, if it exceeds it throws `OutOfMemoryException` and application crashes as `bitmap` is heavy. So can anyone help me out for this. I have to set the image as on `ImageView` using `setImageBitmap(bitmap)` method. unless until m not able to make `Bitmap` reference how can i set it to `ImageView`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I used the following options

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed=false;
options.inSampleSize=10;
options.inScaled=false;
options.inTargetDensity=100;
```

I hope this will work for you as well

Comment: my Bitmap is 10000x10000. if i use inSampleSize image gets blurred.

Comment: in that case you can increase inTargetDensity. I hope that will help

Comment: Thank you let me try i'll tell afterwards Mr. Chhabra. Nice to see a Punjabi boy on Stack :).

Comment: `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` method immediately allots the large size to Bitmap object.

Comment: I think if you will provide options it will not take large size . Have you tried it ?

Comment: yeah i had tried it Brother but it makes image blur as i am sample the image :( . Have you tried to load a large resolution map on the imageView?

Comment: yes  actually I also worked on loading HD wallpapers on image view, so I used the same code as I mentioned above, try to increase inTargetDensity or decrease inSampleSize . Hopefully that will work

Comment: Ok Thanx Brother i'll let you know if i succeed.

Comment: i need as it is image without no quality lose.

Comment: I think there is no other option instead of decreasing the quality a little bit. Can you share code ?

Comment: `      ImageViewTouch iv = (ImageViewTouch) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed=false;
        options.inSampleSize=3;
        options.inScaled=false;
        options.inTargetDensity=100;
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.world_map,options);
        iv.setImageBitmap(b);` this my code

Comment: whats the use of HD image if i have to reduce quality my friend. If one have to reduce the quality from HD image to display it better option is to use the small resolution images instead :(

Comment: In my application, I reduced the size of image  to display it , but when the user clicked to download it , I downloaded HD wallpaper. I have checked your code and everything seems fine

Comment: downloading the file is not an issue at all... displaying the Hd image is the issue and i solved it by my own different method yipiii :) . Thanx for discussion.

Comment: Brother tell me one thing Android Gallery App is able to display the Hd Images why its not possible for us to display the Hd Image in our own application?.

Comment: It will be appreciated if you will post the code by which you were able to solve the problem

Comment: Best Way to implement The large resolution and size images to make their Tiles and display it. Its up to u how u gonna display those tiles whether u r using WebView or u r using ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

The android development reference includes lots of examples and guides for new Android devs.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) you can find a dev guide explaining the bes practices in loading bitmaps in your application.

This solution is about scaling down the in-memory image to the size of your imageView to avoid OutOfMemoryException. Because for very large pictures you don't need to load every single pixel if your screen is only 720p wide for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you testing the app on emulator, then try increasing the size of `VM heap` by editing the AVD. Hope this will help you.

Comment: in the end i have to deploy the apk on the device, in that case i'll be  helpless :(.

Comment: May be not. You can give it a try. I say, try it on any of the device, run your code now on any android device and see. Then notify me whats the result. Just try it.

Answer (score 0):

try decoding your bitmap and then use it.

```
try this

  Bitmap  bitmap =   Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ImageResource,desired height , desired width ,false);
```

Comment: Thanx but i don't need this